# Flexbox row appears as column in VS2015 Update 3 design view

Tags: css, visual-studio-2015

I'm working in Visual Studio 2015 update 3.
I am trying to use Flexbox Display:Flex; to create a simple row of blocks which wrap down as the screen width is reduced.

Using the following code, it looks good as works as expected running in any browser.

However, in design view of VS2015 the container Div is a Block across the screen and the inner div block are displayed as a column.

At first I was working on it in an .aspx page but then I tried a simple .html page, both within the VS2015 environment though.  I've searched all over the web and stack-overflow for the past three days but found no issues similar to my problem.  I'm starting to think it's another VS bug.  I only have Visual Studio as a designer don't know if this is the behavior in all designers or code editors.

THE CSS:

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    }

.flex-container > div {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>  
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>  
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>  
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>  
</div>
```

I would expect to see a row of white boxes on a blue background.  If the width is too narrow for all the white boxes, I would expect to see them wrap to the next line (in design view).  Thanks for any suggestions, confirmations, examples or solutions. :)

Comment: 2015 sounds like a very old version...pre-flexbox?

Comment: vs2015 update 3 released June 27, 2016.  It doesn't predate as best I know.  I would like solid confirmation if there is an issue tho.  Thank.

Comment: Read these [comments](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/75576/html-designer-is-far-from-wysiwyg.html) from Microsoft's developer community forms. Response from MS employees is basically "we're not fixing this, use a real browser"...

Comment: Thank you.  I did read it.  It seemed he was referring to vs2017 and that they had no plans on revising the designer engine as an update to the 2017 ver.  Does anyone here have vs2019 installed that can try that example above?  Has anyone tried it in their own Visual Studio version?  No one has mentioned it.  Thanks for the replies.

Comment: For the records: `display:flex` is still not render correctly in Visual Studio 2022 (version 17.5) with "HTML designer (Web Forms)".